# How to use brush to select circles that are contained in multiple group elements in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm making a scatter plot. The circles in the plot are contained within multiple group elements.

I am attempting to use [brush](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush) to select circles that fall into the extent of my brush. But the parameter in the brushend function gives data for a single group.

How can I change my code so the brushend function knows which groups are brushed over without having to iterate through all of the circles in the plot?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<style>

#plot {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.extent {
  fill: grey;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id=plot>  
<script>

(function() {
  var data = [];

  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var c = Math.random();

    if (c < 0.33) c = "red";
    else if (c < 0.66) c = "green";
    else c = "blue";

    data.push({x: x, y: y, c: c});
  }

  data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.c })
      .entries(data);

  var svg = d3.select("#plot").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 400)
      .attr("height", 400)
      .selectAll("scatter")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .each(scatter);

  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, 400]);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([400, 0]);

  var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(xScale)
      .y(yScale)
      .on("brushend", brushend);

  svg.call(brush);

  function brushend(d) {
  }

})();

function scatter(d) {
  var g = d3.select(this);

  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, 400]);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([400, 0]);

  g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(d.values)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.x) })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.c });
}

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** I realized that the brush doesn't work across group elements, so I accepted an answer that doesn't use the parameter that's passed to the brushend function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing your `brushend` function a bit. The `brush.extent()` function returns the barriers of your brush selection, and what you need to do is select all that fall between those barriers.

```js
  function brushend(d) {
      var e = brush.extent();
  svg.selectAll("circle")
   .classed("hidden", function(d) {
      if(e[0][0] < d.x && d.x < e[1][0]
          && e[0][1] < d.y && d.y < e[1][1]) {
                console.log(d);
      }
      return e[0][0] < d.x && d.x < e[1][0]
          && e[0][1] < d.y && d.y < e[1][1];   });
  } 
})();
```

I am aware that this is not the most elegant way to deal with this, but I will look for a better way of selecting the circles with the function and then edit my answer. I hope for now that this change will allow you to log all circles within the selection to your console.

**EDIT**
I have found a solution that does not need to apply classes to everything, and I am very sure that it works as it should. It is however not pretty, because of the different ways that `brush.extent()` and and your circle's `cx` and `cy` properties work. On the outside it should look fine though.

```js
  function brushend(d) {
      var e = brush.extent();
     var circles = svg.selectAll("circle");
      var ae00 = e[0][0]*4; //The cx and cy values are 4 times as big
      var ae10 = e[1][0]*4;
      var ae01 = 400 - e[0][1]*4; //revert the y values, so 0 is at the top
      var ae11 = 400 - e[1][1]*4;
      for(var j = 0; j < 3; j ++) {
       for (var i = 0; i < circles[j].length; i++) {
       if(ae00 < circles[j][i].cx.animVal.value && circles[j][i].cx.animVal.value < ae10 
           && ae01 > circles[j][i].cy.animVal.value && circles[j][i].cy.animVal.value > ae11) {
                console.log(circles[j][i]);
        }
      }
      }
  }
```